# Правильно я квалифицировала предложение? Спасибо.

Tags: синтаксис

Облизался бедняга и меньшего в пузо - аж загудело.

Сложное предложение с разными видами связи - 
Облизался бедняга и (сочинительная связь) меньшего в пузо - (бессоюзная связь) аж загудело.
Облизался бедняга - простое двусоставное предложение.
Меньшего в пузо - односоставное неполное предложение.
Аж загудело - односоставное полное предложение.

Answer (score 2):

Перед И нет запятой. Значит,союз соединяет однородные члены. Получается, ваше предложение БСП, состоящее из 2-х простых: "Облизался бедняга и меньшего в пузо "(съел,видимо?) - простое, двусост.,"аж загудело" -  простое, односост., безличное (если, конечно, не пузо загудело).

> если загудело пузо

Будет обычное двусоставное: пузо(что сделало?)загудело

Comment: спасибо большое:) А если загудело пузо, тогда будет односоставное определенно-личное?

Comment: Согласна, только в пузо он его, видимо, ударил - так, что загудело.

Comment: Да, ударил. Это предложение, по-видимому, фраза из Тараса Шевченко "Сон" в переводе.

Высмеивание чинопочитания. Там царь ударил чиновника, чиновник бьёт меньшего себя по чину, а тот, в свою очередь, ещё более мелкого чиновника. Могу процитировать, если кому-то интересно подробнее.